# Index of numbers in Nintex workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, nintex

I have numeric field in SharePoint list, let's say value in that is 912 where first digit indicates the year and last two digits indicates some other codes.

So how can we extract this dynamically using Nintex workflow.

The syntax is

Any help is much appreciated.